# SalesforceMalformedRequest Error while querying salesforce through Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am using simple-salesforce & django.

I am performing simple query on Account object of Salesforce.

```
sf1 = Salesforce(connection parameters)

sf8 = sf1.query("SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = testname")
```

Here testname is variable which holds firstname + lastname combination.

I am getting the below error.

```
Exception Type: SalesforceMalformedRequest

Exception Value:Malformed request https://cs90.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account+WHERE+Name+%3D+testname. Response content: [{'message': '\nSELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = testname\n                                   ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:36\nBind variables only allowed in Apex code', 'errorCode': 'MALFORMED_QUERY'}]
```

Any workaround possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `format` to generate query string

```
sf1.query("SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name ='{0}'".format(testname))
```

> Make sure *testname* variable type should be string

Comment: is that right to use concatenation operator to form a query string?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have updated my answer, As he is using python `format` can be used but for string concatenation  `+` is the only way i guess.